# No value accessor for form control with name Angular

Tags: angular6

Estoy intentando hacer en Angular 6 que en un mat-card se muestre los elementos consumidos de una Api pero me sale el siguiente error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso quiero poner en el mat-card-title el nombre de un restaurante.
Ayuda por favoor y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Puedes hacer el [tour] para conocer cómo preguntar y que datos deberías aportar para que te podamos ayudar. No es una buena idea añadir capturas de pantalla para mostrar errores o código cuando se puede copiar el texto. Ese error te está diciendo que en el form no hay un FormControl asociado a "nombre".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carlos. En tu caso, prueba a eliminar el `[(ngModel)]`, ya que éste, se utiliza en un `mat-form`, simplemente colocando `name = "nombre"` te debería funcionar.